Images are not showing after deployment of MERN project on Render hosting platform
This is my server.js file:
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const connectDB = require("./config/db");
const path=require('path');


dotenv.config();


const userRoutes = require("./routes/userRoutes");
const imageRoutes=require('./routes/imageRoutes');


connectDB();


const app = express();

//middelwares
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(express.json());


//routes
app.use('/uploads', express.static(path.join(__dirname, './uploads')));
// console.log(path.join(__dirname, './uploads'));
app.use("/api/v1/user", userRoutes);
app.use("/api/v1/posts", imageRoutes);


// DEPLOY
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,"./client/build")));
app.get('*',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,"./client/build/index.html"));
});


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;


app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(
    `Server Running on  mode port no ${PORT}`
  );
});

This is routes/imageRoutes:
const express = require("express");
const{UploadPostController,getAllPostsController,
    DeletePostController,updatePostController,
    SavePostController,
    LikePostController,
    UnLikePostController,
    UnSavePostController,
    AddCommentController,
    DeleteCommentController,
    GetPostController,
    GetAllCommentsOfPost,
    GetMyPostsController,
    GetAllSavedPostsController,
    UpdateCommentOfPost

}=require('../controllers/imageController')

const authMiddleware= require('../middlewares/authMiddleware')

const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');



// Ensure the uploads directory exists
const uploadDir = path.join(__dirname, '../uploads');
if (!fs.existsSync(uploadDir)) {
  fs.mkdirSync(uploadDir);
}

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, uploadDir);
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + '-' + Math.round(Math.random() * 1E9);
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + uniqueSuffix + path.extname(file.originalname));
  }
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });


//router object
const router = express.Router();


router.get("/feed",authMiddleware, getAllPostsController);

router.post("/upload",upload.single('post') ,authMiddleware,UploadPostController);
router.delete("/delete/:id",authMiddleware, DeletePostController);
router.put("/update/:id",authMiddleware, updatePostController);
router.post("/save/:id",authMiddleware, SavePostController);
router.post("/unsave/:id",authMiddleware, UnSavePostController);

router.post("/like/:id",authMiddleware, LikePostController);
router.post("/unlike/:id",authMiddleware, UnLikePostController);


router.post("/add-Comment/:id",authMiddleware, AddCommentController);
router.get("/getPost/:id", GetPostController);
router.get("/myposts",authMiddleware,GetMyPostsController);
router.get("/savedPosts",authMiddleware,GetAllSavedPostsController);

router.delete("/delete-Comment/:id",authMiddleware, DeleteCommentController);
router.get("/getAll-Comments/:id",authMiddleware, GetAllCommentsOfPost);
router.put("/update-Comment/:id",authMiddleware, UpdateCommentOfPost);





module.exports = router;


Slider.jsx component for displaying all images on frontend:
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Slider = ({ images }) => {

  console.log('SliderImages',images);
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);

  const nextSlide = () => {
    setCurrentIndex((prevIndex) => (prevIndex + 1) % images.length);
  };

  const prevSlide = () => {
    setCurrentIndex((prevIndex) => (prevIndex - 1 + images.length) % images.length);
  };

  return (
    <div className="relative w-full    max-w-6xl mx-auto mt-2 ">
      <div className="relative overflow-hidden rounded-lg shadow-lg  h-4/5 md:h-[35rem] p-2">
        <img
          src={`/opt/render/project/src/uploads/${images[currentIndex].url}`}
          alt={`Slide ${currentIndex}`}
          className=" w-full h-4/5  md:h-full  object-cover rounded-lg"
        />
      </div>
      <button
        onClick={prevSlide}
        className="absolute top-1/2 left-0 transform -translate-y-1/2 p-2 bg-gray-800 text-white rounded-full hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none"
      >
        &#10094;
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={nextSlide}
        className="absolute top-1/2 right-0 transform -translate-y-1/2 p-2 bg-gray-800 text-white rounded-full hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none"
      >
        &#10095;
      </button>
      <div className="flex justify-center mt-4 space-x-2">
        {images.map((_, index) => (
          <button
            key={index}
            onClick={() => setCurrentIndex(index)}
            className={`w-3 h-3 rounded-full ${
              currentIndex === index ? 'bg-blue-500' : 'bg-gray-300'
            }`}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Slider;

When I deploy this project the images are not rendering. I also log the uploads folder path console.log('uploadfolderPath', path.join(__dirname, './uploads')); and I got /opt/render/project/src/uploads on Render console logs, so I changed all src of images with this, but still it is not working. I have added proxy "proxy": "http://localhost:8080" in React client package.json file so how can I resolve this issue and is it that proxy causing any issue?

You shouldn't use the file system on a hosted platform like Render, it's ephemeral. Store the images in S3 or similar. Your client dev server proxy is (hopefully!) irrelevant as it's not being used in production.
